# how can I eliminate unchecked assignment warning in using dom4j Iterator

Tags: java, xml, dom4j

warning code:

```
for (Iterator<Element> iterator = element.elementIterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
   // some code
}
```

warning information:

```
Unchecked assignment: 'java.util.Iterator' to 'java.util.Iterator<org.dom4j.Element>'
```

Comment: How you **initialize** your `element`? Please provide a demo to re-produce your problem.

Comment: Most possibly is that you do not specify the `element` with proper parameterised type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clean way would be to upgrade to the dom4j 2.0 library, which defines elementIterator() to return a parameterized type:
https://dom4j.github.io/javadoc/2.0.0/org/dom4j/Element.html

With your code as-is, you could use a @supressWarnings() annotation to silence the complaint...

Comment: I test my code by using dom4j 2.02, it works. And also thanks for the @supressWarning annotation, it works well